# How to hide/suppress fabric ssh command output to console?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, fabric

Hide/suppress fabric 2.4.0 ssh command execution on remote servers

I read the fabric doc and tried the --no-pty but without success

I execute a bunch of commands on remote servers like below and it Would return the output of that command on my console.

```
ssh_connect.run("sudo /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/admincmd/bppllist -U -verbose -allpolicies | egrep '^Policy Name|Active' | awk '/Active.*yes/{print x};{x=$3}'")
```

I would like to hide\suppress the output of those commands. I would only like it to print stuff if i explicitly use the print() function. I am using fabric version 2.4.0

Comment: please add a more complete example, imports how your are connecting and running. just omit the sensitive information.

Comment: Im using fabric 2.4 to ssh to remote linux servers to execute various commands and from the stdout returned, i would parse through the data and collect what i need to ouput. I would like to avoid the output from being displayed on the console when the commands are executed. 
#from fabric import Connection
#ssh_connection = (hostname, username, pwd)  
#policies = ssh_connect.run("sudo /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/admincmd/bppllist -U -verbose -allpolicies | egrep '^Policy Name|Active' | awk '/Active.*yes/{print x};{x=$3}'")

Comment: this is just what you wrote above, can you provide a [MCVE]?
For example, what you imported, what output you should expect.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to call *run* with "hide=True":

```py
ssh_connect.run(your_command, hide=True)
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/1.2/api/runners.html#invoke.runners.Runner.run) for the 'invoke' library:

> Specify hide='out' (or 'stdout') to hide only the stdout stream,
>   hide='err' (or 'stderr') to hide only stderr, or hide='both' (or True)
>   to hide both streams.

Answer (score 0):

just add `&> /dev/null` to your command

```
ssh_connect.run("sudo /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/admincmd/bppllist -U -verbose -allpolicies | egrep '^Policy Name|Active' | awk '/Active.*yes/{print x};{x=$3}' &> /dev/null")
```

Comment: thanks for your reply and let me clarify what im trying to do. The results of the ssh command is stored in a list. when i try with the "&> /dev/null", the command completes but does not store output in my variable. This is my result: In [4]: policies
Out[4]: <Result cmd="sudo /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/admincmd/bppllist -U -verbose -allpolicies | egrep '^Policy Name|Active' | aw
ive.*yes/{print x};{x=$3}' &> /dev/null" exited=0>

Comment: When i try In policies.stdout
I get empty list, '' , when using the  "&> /dev/null